# $(z-1)e^{-iα}+(z-1)^{-1}e^{i α}$ whose imaginary part is 0.What is equation on which it lies?

Tags: complex-numbers

*Let Y be the imaginary part of $(z-1)e^{-iα}+(z-1)^{-1}e^{i α}$.z is a complex number and  α is real.Then Y=0 implies then what will be the equation of the circle on which z lies ?*

I tried taking z=a+i b and separating the imaginary part,but the expression is coming too complicated and ugly.Is there a better method?Please help.BTW note i'm a beginner,so please explain me in steps or even a little hint will do.Thank you.

Comment: Hint: Use Euler's formula to decompose the expression: $$e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$$

Comment: The gather the imaginary parts and set them to zero. See what you get from that.

Comment: I tried that but the resultant expression which i'm getting is not a good one...check for yourself...I feel there must be a better method..than the one you are intending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$Im[(z-1)e^{-iα}+(z-1)^{-1}e^{iα}]=0$

Now using $Im{Z}= \frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2}$ where $e^{ix}$ is euler representation of any complex number Z.

The expression symplifies to $$(|z-1|^2-1)\left(\frac{(e^{-iα})}{(\frac{|z|^{2}}{z}-1)}-\frac{(e^{iα})}{(z-1)}\right)=0$$
Hence $|z-1|^{2}=1$ is the final result and the equation of the circle.

Comment: $z-1$ could also be a real multiple of $e^{-i\alpha}$, so both terms are real.

Comment: Corrected the typo ;-).